# How to change position of JSON Child to Parent in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a following json data and trying to move the items in to parent position using php

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Information": "Monthly Prices",
        "Symbol": "AAPL",
        "Last Refreshed": "2017-05-31",
        "Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Items": {
        "Item1": {
            "1. open": "145.1000",
            "2. high": "156.6500",
        },
        "Item2": {
            "1. open": "145.1000",
            "2. high": "156.6500",
        }
    }
}
```

i need to change the json as follows using Php script

```
{
        "Data": {
            "Information": "Monthly Prices",
            "Symbol": "AAPL",
            "Last Refreshed": "2017-05-31",
            "Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
        },
        "Item1": {
            "1. open": "145.1000",
            "2. high": "156.6500",
        },
        "Item2": {
            "1. open": "145.1000",
            "2. high": "156.6500",
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: this won't work since your example is not valid json. The trailing comma (,) on the last properties of the Items is not allowed.

```php
// Open json file data.json and convert it to an array
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);

// Loop through Items
foreach($array['Items'] as $key => $value) {
    // Add Item key to parent node in array
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
// Unset Items
unset($array['Items']);

// Save to a new file data_converted.json
file_put_contents('data_converted.json', json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your json decoded data is in `$data` variable.

```
$returnData         = [];
$returnData['Data'] = $data['Data'];
$items              =  $data['Items'];
$returnData         = array_merge($returnData,$items);
```

`$returnData` has your expected result;